# Get select options inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the option values and text from a dropdown select box into an array.

The select box looks like that:

```
<select id="test">

<option value="item/objectcomponents/head/helm_leather_b_06_bef.m2">Object1</option>
<option value="item/objectcomponents/head/helm_leather_b_06_bem.m2">Object2</option>
<option value="item/objectcomponents/head/helm_leather_b_02_bem.m2">Object3</option>

</select>
```

The array structure should look like that:

```
Object1: "helm_leather_b_06_bef.m2"
Object2: "helm_leather_b_06_bem.m2"
Object3: "helm_leather_b_02_bem.m2"
```

As you see the "option values" are shorten.

I tried it like that, but it seems that the "array push" method isn´t the right way.

```
const assets = [];
$('select#test').find('option').each(function () {
    var selectbox = $(this).val();
    var selectbox2 = selectbox.split('.')[0];
    var selectbox3 = selectbox2.split('item/objectcomponents/head/')[1];
    assets.push(selectbox3);
    
    var selectname = $(this).text();
    assets.push(selectname);
});
```

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9btphmc/).

Comment: First obvious issue is that `assets.push('selectbox3');`  should be `assets.push(selectbox3);` - is that the only issue?   You have two `.push` so you'll get 6 entries in your array, which doesn't seem to be what you want - *maybe* you wanted `assets.push(selectname + ": " + selectbox3);` as the last line.  Or maybe you wanted `var o = {}; o[selectname] = selectbox3; assets.push(o);` https://jsfiddle.net/gdk36fxr/

Comment: In jsfiddle (and other IDEs) you can see what each bit of code is by its colour - strings are light yellow, variables are blue.

Comment: Thanks, yes this was the first mistake. I´ve edited my fiddle. Now I just need to find a way to get the right array structure.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/45vb9jhg/) working code.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still `0:, 1:, 2:`. This should be replace with `Object1:, Object2:, Object3:`.

Comment: It's hard to see what your end result is as what you've provided doesn't make much sense (it's a list, not an array and not json).   The fiddle I provided pushes objects which gives the closest I can see, if the requirement is for "an array".   Or you can use `assets[selectname] = selectbox3;` https://jsfiddle.net/bv3zautn/ which also seems to be close to what you're after, without `.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want an array of json objects? You can use this in that case:

```
const assets = [];
$('select#test').find('option').each(function () {
    var selectbox = $(this).val();
    var selectbox2 = selectbox.split('.')[0];
    var selectbox3 = selectbox2.split('item/objectcomponents/head/')[1];
    var selectname = $(this).text();
    assets.push({selectname:selectbox3});
});

console.log(assets);
```

Output: `[{Object1: "helm_leather_b_06_bef"}, {Object2: "helm_leather_b_06_bem"}, {Object3: "helm_leather_b_02_bem"}]`

If you just want one json object with the inner text as the keys, you can achieve that with this:

```
const assets = {};
$('select#test').find('option').each(function () {
    var selectbox = $(this).val();
    var selectbox2 = selectbox.split('.')[0];
    var selectbox3 = selectbox2.split('item/objectcomponents/head/')[1];
    
    var selectname = $(this).text();
    assets[selectname] = selectbox3;
});

console.log(assets);
```

Output:

```
{
    Object1: "helm_leather_b_06_bef", 
    Object2: "helm_leather_b_06_bem", 
    Object3: "helm_leather_b_02_bem"
}
```